# How to inject a commit between some two arbitrary commits in the past?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Suppose I have the following commit history on my local-only branch:

```
A -- B -- C
```

How do I insert a new commit between `A` and `B`?

Comment: I have a very similar question on [how to insert a new version in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678238/how-to-inject-a-version-between-some-two-arbitrary-versions-in-the-past) instead of a commit.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

It's even easier than in OP's answer.

1. `git rebase -i <any earlier commit>`. This displays a list of commits in your configured text editor.
2. Find the commit you want to insert after (let's assume it's `a1b2c3d`). In your editor, for that line, change `pick` to `edit`.
3. Begin the rebase by closing your text editor (save your changes). This leaves you at a command prompt with the commit you chose earlier (`a1b2c3d`) *as if it has just been committed*.
4. Make your changes and `git commit` (**NOT** amending, unlike most `edit`s). This creates new a commit *after* the one you chose.
5. `git rebase --continue`. This replays the successive commits, leaving your new commit inserted in the correct place.

Beware that this will rewrite history, and break anyone else who tries to pull.

Comment: This added the new commit after the commit, which is after the one that I was rebasing onto (also the last commit), instead of right after the one I was rebasing onto. The result was same as if I had simply made a new commit at the end with the changes I wanted to insert. My history became `A -- B -- C -- D` instead of desired `A -- D -- B -- C`.

Comment: @XedinUnknown: Then you didn't use Rebase properly.

Comment: Apparently. I guess I misread, and rebased _onto_ the commit before the one I needed, marking the commit I wanted to add _before_ as "edit".

Comment: What does the `after to edit` mean in "Change the commit you want to insert after to edit" ? Also, `Begin the rebase` is also not clear what does it mean - make the changes or run some other command?

Comment: @Aleks: I mean change the prefix in its line in the rebase editor.  And "begin" means close the editor

Comment: To use this answer, first you have to identify the new commit. In one case, this could just be at the tip; let's call it `D`, so we have `A - B - C - D` and the goal is `A - D - B - C`.   `git rebase -i HEAD~4`, and reorder the commits to ADBC order in the editor, save, exit.

Comment: Now `D` could be a commit anywhere. Suppose we have `A - B - C` and we have some commit `D` which is not even in this branch.  We know its SHA however,  We can do `git rebase -i HEAD~3`. Now between the `A` and `B` `pick` lines, we insert a **new** `pick` line which says `pick SHA`, giving the hash of the desired `D`. It need not be the full hash, just the shortened one.  **`git rebase -i` just cherry picks whatever commits are listed by `pick` lines in the buffer; they don't have to be the original ones that it listed for you.**

Comment: Using this method, is there a way to introduce a new commit _before_ A? I know that I can always just checkout the current parent of A, then create a new commit X and then rebase the whole of A--B--C on top of X. It would be simpler however if I could just use interactive rebase and specify "edit" for the parent of A.

Comment: @StephenFriedrich Parent of A is `A~1`, so you can pass this as an argument for `rebase`.

Comment: If you want to insert a new commit right after a *merge commit* `a1b2c3d`, the described answer will get rid of the merge commit, which is likely not what you want. Use the `--preserve-merges` (`-p`) option to prevent this from happening (e.g., `git rebase -i a1b2c3d~`, then continue as described)

Comment: @Kaz This looks like a different, valid answer.

Comment: @Kaz I would encourage you to submit this as a separate answer, and I would support it as the accepted answer. It's insightful, simple, to-the-point, and appears correct, and is exactly on target. These other answers are good, but more hacky imho.

Comment: Even easier, you can use the `break` keyword in the editor on its own line in between two commits (or on the first line, to insert a commit before your specified commit).

Comment: I agree with @XedinUnknown ; this created the commit after where OP wants it. Will try `break` as mentioned by @SimonT

Comment: This works great! For <any earlier commit> I had to pick the commit *two* positions before the insertion position though (since rebase first line with `pick` will show the commit just after that, and then I need to insert yet another commit after that). Not sure how to make it work if you need to insert a commit right after initial commit. There's probably a trick to do something before the first rebase action, but not sure how.

Comment: Works exactly as described, starting with `git rebase <commit>~1`. Only thing I'd add is that `git status` will report the divergence with the remote and recommend a `git pull`, which is not what I needed. I used `git push --force` to get my rebase to origin.

Answer (score 58):

Turns out to be quite simple, the answer found [here](https://printf2linux.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/insert-a-commit-in-the-past-git/). Suppose you're on a branch `branch`. Perform these steps:

- create a temporary branch from the commit after which you want to insert the new commit (in this case commit `A`):

  ```
   git checkout -b temp A
  ```
- perform the changes and commit them, creating a the commit, let's call it `N`:

  ```
   git commit -a -m "Message"
  ```

(or `git add` followed by `git commit`)

- rebase the commits you want to have after the new commit (in this case commits `B` and `C`) onto the new commit:

  ```
   git rebase temp branch
  ```

<sup>(possibly you need to use `-p` to preserve merges, if there were any - thanks to [a no longer existing comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315156/how-to-inject-a-commit-between-some-two-arbitrary-commits-in-the-past/32315157?noredirect=1#comment73409773_32315157) by [ciekawy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3021889/ciekawy))</sup>

- delete the temporary branch:

  ```
   git branch -d temp
  ```

After this, the history looks as follows:

```
A -- N -- B -- C
```

It is of course possible that some conflicts will appear while rebasing.

In case your branch is not local-only this will introduce rewriting history, so might cause serious problems.

Comment: I couldn't follow the accepted answer by SLaks, but this worked for me. After I got the commit history I wanted, I had to `git push --force` to change the remote repo.

Comment: When using rebase using the -Xtheirs option auto resolves conflicts correctly, so `git rebase temp branch -Xtheirs`. Helpful answer for injecting in a script!

Comment: For noobs like myself I'd like to add that after `git rebase temp branch`, but before `git branch -d temp`, all you have to do is fix and stage merging conflicts and issue `git rebase --continue`, i.e. no need to commit anything, etc.

Comment: Instead of `git rebase -p temp branch`, you may need to use `git rebase --rebase-merges temp branch` for newer versions of Git.

Answer (score 47):

Here's a strategy that avoids doing an "edit hack" during the rebase seen in the other answers I've read.

By using `git rebase -i` you obtain a list of commits since that commit.
Just add a "break" at the top of the file, this will cause the rebase to break at that point.

```
break
pick <B's hash> <B's commit message>
pick <C's hash> <C's commit message>
```

Once launched, `git rebase` will now stop at the point of the "break".
You can now edit your files and create your commit normally.
You can then continue the rebase with `git rebase --continue`. This may cause conflicts you'll have to fix. If you get lost, don't forget you can always abort using `git rebase --abort`.

This strategy can be generalised to insert a commit anywhere, just put the "break" at the spot where you want to insert a commit.

After rewriting history, don't forget to `git push -f`. The usual warnings about other people fetching your branch apply.

Comment: Right. My answer also does not use "edit" feature of rebase. Still, this is yet another valid approach - thanks! :-)

Comment: This is by far the best solution!

Comment: Appreciate the use of `rebase -i`.  Makes a lot of cherry-picking way easier to keep track of.

Comment: This should be on top... no need to mess with edit for this

Answer (score 45):

Even easier solution:

1. Create your new commit at the end, D. Now you have:

   ```
   A -- B -- C -- D
   ```
2. Then run:

   ```
   $ git rebase -i hash-of-A
   ```
3. Git will open your editor and it will look like this:

   ```
   pick 8668d21 B
   pick 650f1fc C
   pick 74096b9 D
   ```
4. Just move D to the top like this, then save and quit

   ```
   pick 74096b9 D
   pick 8668d21 B
   pick 650f1fc C
   ```
5. Now you will have:

   ```
   A -- D -- B -- C
   ```

Comment: Nice idea, however it may be hard to introduce D on C, when you intend these changes being wrt. to A.

Comment: I have a situation where I have 3 commits that I want to rebase together and a commit in the middle that is unrelated. This is super nice to be able to just move that commit earlier or later down the line of commits.

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm not quite following. Can you explain that case in more detail? I think you mean that if D & C both edit fileX, and the edits to fileX in D essentially depend on edits to fileX in C, it'll be hard to move D up, but it feels like that situation would preclude asking the original question... Would another answer here prevent the issue you're referring to?

Comment: @ruffin No, I meant that edits in D are easier to be made in state A. I'm not saying this invalidates the answer or precludes anything - I said "may be hard", so only referring to a (possibly small) subset of scenarios :)

Answer (score 16):

*Many good answers here already. I just wanted to add a "no rebase" solution, in 4 easy steps.*

---

**Summary**

```
git checkout A
# <<< modify your files at this point
git commit -am "Message for commit D"
git cherry-pick A..C
git branch -f master HEAD
```

---

**Explanation**

(Note : one advantage of this solution is that you don't touch your branch until the final step, when you're 100% sure you're OK with the end result, so you have a very handy **"pre-confirmation" step allowing for AB testing**.)

---

*Initial state* (I've assumed `master` for your branch name)

```
A -- B -- C <<< master <<< HEAD
```

---

**1) Start by pointing HEAD at the right place**

```
git checkout A

     B -- C <<< master
    /
   A  <<< detached HEAD
```

(Optionnally here, rather than detaching HEAD, we could have created a temporary branch with `git checkout -b temp A`, which we would need to delete at the end of the process. Both variants work, do as you prefer since everything else remains the same)

---

**2) Create the new commit D to be inserted**

```
# at this point, make the changes you wanted to insert between A and B, then

git commit -am "Message for commit D"

     B -- C <<< master
    /
   A -- D <<< detached HEAD (or <<< temp <<< HEAD)
```

---

**3) Then bring copies of the last missing commits B and C** (the command would be the same even if there were more commits in between, since this is picking a range of commits)

```
git cherry-pick A..C

# (if any, resolve potential conflicts between D and these last commits)

     B -- C <<< master
    /
   A -- D -- B' -- C' <<< detached HEAD (or <<< temp <<< HEAD)
```

**( comfortable AB Testing here if needed )**

Now is the moment to inspect your code, test anything that needs to be tested, and you can also diff / compare / inspect *what you had* and *what you would get* after the operations, simply by checking alternatively `C` or `C'`.

---

**4)** Depending on your tests between `C` and `C'`, either it is OK or it is KO.

(EITHER) **4-OK) Finally, move the ref of `master`**

```
git branch -f master HEAD

     B -- C <<< (B and C are candidates for garbage collection)
    /
   A -- D -- B' -- C' <<< master
```

(OR) **4-KO) Just leave `master` unchanged**

If you created a temporary branch, just delete it with `git branch -d <name>`, but if you went for the detached HEAD route, no action needed at all at this point, the new commits will be eligible for garbage collection just after you reattach `HEAD` with a `git checkout master`

In both those cases (OK or KO), at this point just checkout `master` again to reattach `HEAD`.

Comment: Great answer. What will happen if there is `A -- B -- C -- E -- F` and, `B` and `E` are merge commits?

Comment: My answer (like most here) is addressing non-merge commits. If merges are involved, it's more complicated. Depending on the context, it could be better to cherry-pick the (non-merge) commits these merge commits brought, rather than cherry-picking the merge commits, which may or may not be tricky. If you really consider cherry-picking merge commits, take a look at the [`-m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt--mltparent-numbergt) option.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that the commit history is `preA -- A -- B -- C`, if you want to insert a commit between `A` and `B`, the steps are as follows:

1. `git rebase -i hash-of-preA`
2. Git will open your editor. The content may like this:

   ```
   pick 8668d21 A
   pick 650f1fc B
   pick 74096b9 C
   ```

   Change the first `pick` to `edit`:

   ```
   edit 8668d21 A
   pick 650f1fc B
   pick 74096b9 C
   ```

   Save and Exit.
3. Modify your code and then `git add . && git commit -m "I"`
4. `git rebase --continue`

Now your Git commit history is `preA -- A -- I -- B -- C`

---

If you encounter a conflict, Git will stop at this commit. You can use `git diff` to locate conflict markers and resolve them. After resolving all conflicts, you need to use `git add <filename>` to tell Git that the conflict has been resolved and then rerun `git rebase --continue`.

If you want to undo the rebase, use `git rebase --abort`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the commit you want to insert is identified by `D`:

```sh
# Temporarily append the commit you want to insert to the end 
git cherry-pick D
# Results in D -- A -- B -- C

# Start interactive rebase
git rebase -i B^
# Let's imagine that this is what the rebase prompt looks like:
# pick B Third commit
# pick A Second commit
# pick D First commit
# Then reorder the commits:
# pick B Third commit
# pick D First commit
# pick A Second commit
# Save and exit
# After completing the rebase you will find
# A -- D -- B -- C
```

Comment: Your answer is extremely similar to [Matthew's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46413513/1057485), albeit being less explanative. I guess it's the reason someone downvoted?