# Push commits in between other two

Tags: git

is it possible to go from this:

```
a--b--c--f
       \
        d--e
```

to this?

```
a--b--c--d--e--f
```

I'm a bit lost on this one. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315156/how-to-inject-a-commit-between-some-two-arbitrary-commits-in-the-past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece missing from your diagram is the branch names that point to commits `f` and `e`:

```
a--b--c--f   <-- branch_f
       \
        d--e   <-- branch_e
```

You cannot literally *move* commit `f`: a commit, once made, is quite permanent and unchange-able.  You can, however, *copy* commit `f` to a new commit that's a lot like `f`, but different in some way(s).

What you want is a commit that is like `f`, except that it has `e` as its parent, and probably has a different source base (`e`'s source rather than `c`'s).

#### Cherry picking

To get this kind of copy, one can use `git cherry-pick`, which literally just makes the copy:

```
$ git checkout branch_e
$ git cherry-pick branch_f
```

giving:

```
a--b--c--f   <-- branch_f
       \
        d--e--f'  <-- branch_e (HEAD)
```

Note that we've added the new commit `f'` (the copy) to the *current* branch, `branch_e`.

#### Rebasing

Instead of using `git cherry-pick`, we can use `git rebase`.  This copies some number of commits, automatically:

```
$ git checkout branch_f
$ git rebase branch_e
```

The set of commits that get copied are those on the current branch—which is why we have to check out `branch_f` first—that aren't on the *other* branch, which is why we tell it `branch_e`.

The place it copies them to, is "after the tip of the other branch".

Once it finishes making the copy, `git rebase` "peels away" the label `branch_f` from where it was before, and moves it to after the last-copied commit:

```
a--b--c--f   [abandoned]
       \
        d--e   <-- branch_e
            \
             f'  <-- branch_f (HEAD)
```

Note that this is the same set of commits as before: the key difference is that `branch_e` has not moved (still points to `e`) and `branch_f` *has* moved (now points to new copy `f'`).

(Also, the current branch is `branch_f` this time.)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. Git cannot move commits, it can only copy and create new, different commits. To achieve want you want do

```
git checkout e
git cherry-pick f
```

You will have

```
a--b--c--d--e--f`
```

where f` is a copy of f.