# How can I insert a commit at a specific history position and rewrite history for all paths?

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I want to do what's specifically asked on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315156/how-to-inject-a-commit-between-some-two-arbitrary-commits-in-the-past) but I want to get it effective for all paths on the git repository, just like you achieve when you perform rewritings with `git filter-branch --all`.

Is that possible with any rebase or filter-branch technique or any third party tool?

Comment: "for all paths" : do you mean "for all branches in my repo" ?

Comment: @LeGEC yes, I prefer using the work path since not all leafs are handled by a branch, a git history path can be kept alive by also by a tag.

Comment: I don't think there is any better way than checkout every "path" manually and do `git rebase` described in the linked answer.