# Git - Move file in old commit

Tags: git, azure

I have a problem in git and I need help. This is setup:

- I have a feature branch in git. `refactor_database`
- This feature branch is now ready to merge in master.
- The first commit of this branch is 3 months old
- There are no conflicts

**previously there was one file**

- 1) `"db/db.service.ts"`

**now there are 3 files:**

- 1) `"db/db.service.ts"`
- 2) `"indexed-db/indexed-db.service.ts"`
- 3) `"sqlite/sqlite.service.ts"`

1 (db.service.ts) previously had the contents of 2 (indexed-db.service) in it.
Now 1 is only a wrapper, that forwards method calls to 2 or 3 depending on some conditions.

**However I did a mistake 3 months ago and I did not realize it until now:**

- Git thinks 1 is the old file and has a ton of changes in it - actually it is a new file
- Git thinks 2 is a completely new file. However it is just the the file, that used to be 1 (the file moved)

**This screenshot makes the problem clear:**
I want the "+" to be @ db.service.ts and sqlite.service.ts.

indexed-db should be a rename of db.service instead of a new file(+)

[image]

My question is:
**Can i retrospectively repair this? If so, how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing one of git's limitations here.
The only way git has to track a same file which has been renamed is by using heuristics, so depending on your commit, it may eventually not be able to understand it. A good practice to help git following moved files is to make unitary move commits.

Maybe you already know that and that is why you are asking for a way to amend your commit:

If I were you, I would look for the hash of the commit just before yours and `git rebase -i <hash>`.

The interactive rebase lets you "edit" a commit in the list. You could here amend your commit and make it unitary, then `git rebase --continue`.

Think about pushing in a new branch when you did this because you will not be able to push without forcing and, I'm cautious, I don't do that.

Maybe a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315156/how-to-inject-a-commit-between-some-two-arbitrary-commits-in-the-past)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation. I will try with the interactive rebase  in a new branch. If it doesn't work out, I just have to live with it. (And next time be more careful when renaming stuff)