# Remove changes to file in old, already pushed, git commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have an old commit, `A`. When I committed `A`, I changed 2 files: `F1` and `F2`. I want to change A, so it only modifies file `F1`. I want to commit `F2` separately. I do *not* want to delete `F1` from my git repository.

I tried doing this by

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 // The exact number doesn't matter, I just change "pick" to "edit" next to A
git reset HEAD^ // unstage all changes
git add F1 // don't add F2, we want to commit it separately
git rebase --continue
```

However, this gives the error

```
F2: needs update
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
```

I solve the problem by doing `git rebase --skip`

However, this removes commit `A` from the git history completely.

What am I doing wrong?

I looked at other posts on SO, and tried the solutions, but they didn't work.

Comment: Have you already pushed this branch to the remote, and is it already shared?  If so, then you should probably _not_ be attempting to rewrite the branch history via git rebase.

Comment: No one else has pulled this branch yet. Also, once I merge this branch, I can delete it, so I imagine there shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315156/how-to-inject-a-commit-between-some-two-arbitrary-commits-in-the-past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost did what @Tim's post suggested, except I had to add in 1 command. Here's what I did:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 // The exact number doesn't matter, I just change "pick" to "edit" next to A
git reset HEAD^ // unstage all changes
git add F2
git commit -m "Add F2"
git add F1
git commit -m "Add F1"
git rebase --continue
```

The `git reset HEAD^` was not mentioned in the linked post.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 //Change "pick" to "edit" for commit to change
git reset HEAD^ -- F2 //reset F2 to previous version in staging area
git commit --amend //replace current commit with F1 change only
git add F2 // add new F2 back to staging area
git commit //commit F2 in a separate commit
git rebase --continue
```

Note that this, as all rebases, rewrites history, and so should only be done if the commits have not yet been pushed to a public repository.

Comment: Use `git status` liberally to double check what is going on at all stages.