# How to unstage a file during interactive rebase (remove file from old commit)?

Tags: git

I've read in *Pro Git* book about interactive rebases to change several commits. So I'm doing `git rebase HEAD~3`, changed one which I wanted to amend to `edit`. Then I was able to change a message via `git commit --amend`. And added a file via `git add file3` after which `git commit --amend` started to output "3 files changed" instead of previous "2 files". But how to remove a file? Why neither `git restore --staged file1` nor `git reset HEAD file1` works? (output of  `git commit --amend` remains "3 files changed" and output of `git log --patch` still shows `file1` for a commit with most recent amended commit message).

I've used web search and read [What is the `git restore` command and what is the difference between `git restore` and `git reset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003030/what-is-the-git-restore-command-and-what-is-the-difference-between-git-restor) (as seen above tried both `restore` and `reset`), [Remove files from Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481639/remove-files-from-git-commit) (talks about last commit), [Remove file commited in old commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68374103/remove-file-commited-in-old-commit) (as I understood `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch <path_to_file>" HEAD` removes a file from all commits in a branch).

There is also not upvoted answer [Remove changes to file in old, already pushed, git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795826/remove-changes-to-file-in-old-already-pushed-git-commit) with

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 //Change "pick" to "edit" for commit to change
git reset HEAD^ -- F2 //reset F2 to previous version in staging area
```

Is it that to remove a file one need to reset whole commit? One cannot remove a single file during rebase?

Comment: Is the file you want to remove only added/changed in one commit, or has it been present for a long time in your repository with multiple modifications across many commits?

Comment: @AlexisMäättäVinkler, I want to remove file from that edited commit, file was present before and I want to commit changes to it as separate commit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you talk about *removing a file* during interactive rebase, you might mean one of two things:

- Making the file *match the previous commit*.  Some would call this *removing the changes to the file*, and since some people think of commits *as* changes, some people will then shorten this to *removing the file*.
- Literally removing the file, so that your new-and-improved commit *omits* the file.

Both are relatively easy to do.  Before I say how to do it, I'll put in some background.

#### Background

To understand what you're doing and why, it helps to have the right mental model of Git commits:

- Each commit has a unique number (*hash ID* or *OID*, where OID stands for Object ID).  The commit's number is how Git really finds the commit: *branch names* don't actually matter.
- All Git commits—in fact, all Git internal objects—are completely read-only.  You can't *change* a commit, so that's not what `git rebase` really does.
- Each commit stores two things: (a) a snapshot of *all* files, and (b) some metadata.

The files in a commit snapshot are compressed and Git-ified and, importantly, *de-duplicated* (both within and across commits) when the contents of some file match the contents of some other file.  So the fact that most commits mostly contain all the files from most previous commits doesn't cause the repository to bloat: these duplicated files are stored only once.  Git handles this all invisibly, and pretty well, as long as you don't store large, incompressible binary files in Git (if you do, then Git handles this poorly and the repository bloats up and becomes unusable).  But this also means that commits *don't* store *changes*.

The *metadata* in a commit records stuff like who made the commit, when, and why (their log message), but it also records data that's crucial for Git's internal operation: each commit stores a list of *parent commit* hash IDs.  This list is usually exactly one element long, giving each commit a single parent.  The parent commit has a snapshot too, and to turn a commit into changes (for viewing purposes), Git extracts both snapshots and sees which files are changed.  Because of the de-duplication, Git can short-circuit this and not bother extracting the identical files at all; it then only has to come up with a change-recipe for files that *don't* match in the two commits.  That's what you see with `git show` or `git log -p`: a diff from the commit's (single) parent's snapshot to the commit's snapshot.

Because commits are read-only, and only Git itself can *read* them, we don't actually work on or with the commits.  Instead, when we pick some commit to use, we have Git *extract* the commit, like un-tar-ing or un-rar-ing some archive, into a working area, which Git calls our *working tree* or *work-tree*.  While these work-tree files are extracted *from* Git, they're not actually *in* Git at all, while you get your work done.

Because commits are read-only, `git rebase` can't *fix* any bad commit, nor does `git commit --amend` change a commit.  Instead, Git makes use of the fact that humans—unlike Git itself—never<sup>1</sup> find a commit by hash ID.  Instead, we use *branch names*.  A branch name simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit we want to claim to be "part of the branch".  That commit then holds, in its metadata, the hash ID of the *previous* commit, which holds in *its* metadata the hash ID of another even-earlier commit, and so on.  This produces a simple backwards-looking chain:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

where the branch name holds the hash ID of the *last* commit `H` in the chain, and everything works backwards from there.

When we add commits in the normal everyday fashion, Git makes a new (read-only) commit `I` whose parent is `H`, adds that to the chain, and writes the hash ID of new commit `I` into the branch name:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

To "amend" commit `H`, Git simply writes new commit `I` with commit `G` as its parent, instead of commit `H`, resulting in:

```
       H
      /
...--G--I   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

Commit `H` still exists, but unless we've memorized its hash ID, we'll never *see* it again.  (*Git* can, as long as Git can find its hash ID.)

Rebasing simply consists of making *more than one* new-and-improved commit.  If we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

and we want a revised `I` to appear *after* `H` instead of before / in-parallel-with it, we make a new snapshot-and-metadata commit `I'` (that otherwise looks like `I`, except that we pick up `H`'s snapshot as our "base" and "re-add" our changes from `I`, hence "re-base"-ing `I`):

```
             I'  <-- HEAD [detached]
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

We then repeat this for commit `J` to get `J'`:

```
             I'-J'  <-- HEAD [detached]
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Once we've copied *all* the commits to new-and-improved ones, we have Git move the *name* `feature` to point to the last copied commit:

```
             I'-J'  <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

The original commits still exist; we just can't find them.

---

<sup>1</sup>(insert Gilbert & Sullivan HMS Pinafore routine here)

---

#### Interactive rebase

Interactive rebase uses the same process as non-interactive rebase,<sup>2</sup> but lets us stop and make adjustments.  To do that, Git provides us with an instruction sheet.  It contains, initially, a series of `pick` commands for each commit that we will copy.  These instruct Git to run `git cherry-pick`, which is the step that copies a commit, like `I` to `I'` above.

Changing `pick` to `edit` makes Git do the cherry-pick, but then stop in the detached-HEAD mode.  Note that here we're copying `I` to `I'` and placing it in the same physical position as before, rather than moving it to come after commit `H`:

```
          I'  <-- HEAD [detached]
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Now that we're in this state, we can use `git commit --amend` to make *yet another* commit, `I"`.  In this commit, we can store any snapshot we like, and use any commit message we like.  The parent of `I"` will be `H`, the same as the parent of `I` and `I'`.

The *snapshot* that goes into the new commit has the same source as any new Git commit: it comes from Git's *index* [AKA](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aka) *staging area*.  This currently contains all the files from commit `I'`, which match all the files from commit `I` (and hence do and will use no space as they're all duplicates that are pre-de-duplicated already).  These are the Git-ified copies of the files that are also in your work-tree.  So you can modify or remove the file in your work-tree and run `git add`:

```
vim foo.py
git add foo.py
```

or:

```
rm foo.py
git add foo.py
```

The `git add` step tells Git to make the index copy match the working tree copy, by reading and compressing and de-duplicating the file, or—after removing `foo.py`—*removing* the index copy entirely.  Or:

```
git rm foo.py
```

combines the `rm` and `git add` into a single step.  Either way we've arranged for the correct (updated or removed) file to be in Git's index, so we now run `git commit --amend`, just as you did:

```
git commit --amend
```

This shoves commit `I'` up out of the way, leaving commit `I"` pointing to `H`:

```
         I'  [abandoned]
        /
        | I"  <-- HEAD [detached]
        |/
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Running `git rebase --continue` tells the rebase code to proceed on to the next instruction in the instruction sheet: another `pick`, or `edit`, or `reword`, or whatever.  Once the last instruction has been followed, rebase will yank the branch name around as before:

```
         I'  [abandoned]
        /
        | I"-J'  <-- feature (HEAD)
        |/
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

(The abandoned commits sit around for a while—at least 30 days by default, in the usual setup—and then Git eventually notices that they've gone unused for long enough, drops the reflog entries that are keeping them alive, and purges them for real.  Until then, though, you can easily get the originals back.  Note that the special name `ORIG_HEAD` also remembers commit `J` for a while, until you do something else that has Git overwrite `ORIG_HEAD` with another hash ID.  Right after a successful rebase, if you don't like the result, `ORIG_HEAD` works just as well as the reflog entry in `branch@{1}`.)

---

<sup>2</sup>In older versions of Git, there were numerous technical differences.  In modern Git, these are largely gone now, though you can still invoke them on purpose if you really want to.  I will also elide a number of optimizations Git normally uses for the kind of interactive rebase you'll be doing, that do make things better for Git but don't change the final outcome here.

---

#### We can now see what `git reset` or `git restore` will do

> Why neither `git restore --staged file1` nor `git reset HEAD file1` works?

Both `git reset` and `git restore` will read a file's content from somewhere and write that file's content to somewhere.  The `git reset` command itself is absurdly complicated, so it's better to stick with the newer, better-focused (more limited) `git restore` in my opinion, but either one will work: we just have to know several things here.

> ```
> git reset HEAD^ -- F2 //reset F2 to previous version in staging area
> ```

Here, we're using `git reset`, not `git restore`, in its restore-one-file mode of operation.  If we use:

```
git reset HEAD -- file1
```

we are telling Git: *read the Git-ified copy of `file1` from the commit specified by `HEAD`*.  If we use:

```
git reset HEAD^ -- F2
```

we are telling Git: *read the Git-ified copy of `F2` from the commit specified by `HEAD^`.*

In both cases, having read the specified file from the specified commit, `git reset` writes the (Git-ified, pre-de-duplicated) content into the index / staging-area, ready to go into the new commit.  The name of the file in the staging area is the same as the name of the file in the chosen commit (`file1` or `F2`).  The *working tree copy* of the file is not changed here!  This is undesirable, since it makes it hard to see what you're doing, but since Git isn't actually *using* the working tree copy at this point, it's not exactly *harmful* right now either.

Using `git checkout` is better:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- F2
```

This form of `git checkout`—which, like `git reset`, is absurdly complicated, which in turn is why `git checkout` was split into `git switch` and `git restore` in Git 2.23—reads a file from the specified commit and writes it to *both* Git's index *and* your working tree.  This makes it much easier to see what you have done, since the working tree copy is now obvious.

If your goal is to make the copy of `F2` in the new `I"` commit match the copy in commit `H`, these `HEAD^` forms of the command will do the trick.  The reason is that `HEAD` currently names commit `I'`, the copy of commit `I`.  `I'`'s parent is `H`, so retrieving the copy of file `F2` (or `file1`) from commit `H` will restore the index and working tree version to match that *in* `H`, and now the commit you make with `git commit --amend`—the `I"` commit—has in it the same copy of that file (de-duplicated).

If your goal is to truly *remove* `F2` entirely, so that commit `I"` has no file `F2` at all, `git rm F2` (or `git rm -- F2` to avoid problems with files named `--cached`, for instance) will do that.

If we want to make `F2` match the copy in `H`, but using `git restore` to avoid the overly-complicated-checkout-command-related errors, we'd run:

```
git restore -SW --source=HEAD^ -- F2
```

for instance.  This does the same as the `git checkout`: we specify `HEAD^` as the source for the file, `-S` (`--staged`) to tell `git restore` to write the file to the staging area, and `-W` (`--worktree`) to tell `git restore` to write the file to our working tree.

Note that in all cases, our goal here is to *make the index contain the correct files* as `git commit --amend` is going to make the new snapshot from Git's index.  Being humans, we should generally update the working tree copy of these files at the same time, since we can't *see* the index (staging area) copy, but we *can* see, in whatever editor or file viewer we prefer, the working tree copy.

We must also remember that if and when we run `git status`, Git will run two `git diff --name-status` operations for us:

- One will compare the `HEAD` commit vs Git's index.  But the `HEAD` commit is commit `I'`, not commit `H`!  So we need not to pay too much attention to this.
- The other will compare Git's index vs our working tree.  This diff should, ideally, be empty, so that we're looking at the same files in our working tree as Git will be using in our next commit.

#### The `reset --soft` option

There's one other thing we *can* do, which I myself never actually do: instead of `git commit --amend`, we can start out the whole amending process with `git reset --soft`.  That is, we start `git rebase -i`, change one `pick` to edit, write out the instruction sheet, and let rebase begin.  We're now in this state:

```
          I'  <-- HEAD [detached]
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

The `git reset --soft` command lets us move the detached `HEAD` without changing *either* Git's index *or* our working tree at all.  Running `git reset --soft HEAD^` produces this:

```
          I'  [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H   <-- main, HEAD [detached]
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

That is, we give up commit `I'` *right away*.  We have most of what we want in Git's index / staging-area and in our working tree.  By giving up `I'` entirely, we now have things arranged *as if* we'd never made commit `I` at all: the *current commit* is now `H`, not `I`.

We can now `git restore -SW --source HEAD -- file1`, if that's what we want.  In fact, with `-S`, `--source HEAD` is the default, so we can shorten this to:

```
git restore -SW -- file1
```

which will copy the committed `file1` from commit `H`—our now-adjusted `HEAD`—to both Git's index and our working tree, discarding any *changes* we had made in commit `I`.  Now `git status` and `git diff --cached` give us the same results we'd get if we were doing this commit for the first time.

(It might be nice if the `edit` mode of `rebase -i` had always done this automatically, but it doesn't, and it's now far too late to change it.)

Comment: Thank you. As I proof I've tried to read all I think you made a "misprint": [and "re-add" our changes from `I`, hence "re-base"-ing `I`] not [and "re-add" our changes from `G`, hence "re-base"-ing `I`]. From your answer I understood it is the source of restore that was incorrect, now I did `git restore --staged --source=HEAD^ -- file1` and it worked at that point: "2 files changed" after `git commit --amend`.

Comment: Yep. And thanks for the typo/brain-o fix!

Comment: After all this lecture there is no clear answer to "removing the changes to the file".

Answer (score 1):

```
git rebase -i <hash>
# edit action on commit list to show 'edit'
# when rebase plays and on that edit commit:
git --amend
git reset HEAD~1
```