# Prepare a Git repository for a coding workshop: branch per lesson or directory per lesson

Tags: git

I am once again preparing a Git repository for a coding workshop - and once again I am wondering whether I should prepare a branch/tag per lesson or a directory per lesson.

In the past I usually settled for branch or tag per lesson. It would contain the solution I prepared and each lesson would add bits'n pieces to the solution of the previous lesson. Hence, students will build an application that evolves with each lesson.

I think there a only minor differences in terms of usability for students to follow along. Either approach works well.

However, preparing such a structure may be rather time consuming. This is unless you get everything right the first time. If you don't you have to go back and tweak the Git history thereby [injecting new commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32315156/131929) or amending old ones. It's quite likely you'll have to resolve conflicts at some point. Also, you might have to move tags.

On the other hand if you choose to create a directory for every lesson you might have to copy-paste changes across multiple directories. Say you forgot two lines in the code for lesson 3. It is quite likely you will need to manually copy those two lines into every lesson that follows.

If there's an obvious solution to this problem, what is it?

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is a Git problem, since Git is not made for this kind of thing.

Comment: Git was made to track Linux kernel development, true. It has since evolved quite a bit and people use for all sorts of things. I tagged this Q with Git because its the VCS I am using. If I were to use SVN or CVS answers would likely be different.

Comment: #1 Does your workshop  have separate lessons like @konglomora said? #2 Or Do you learn to build incrementally one application?

Comment: @JRichardsz it's the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> preparing such a structure may be rather time consuming

Don't bother with any of it, if you're presenting successive refinements approaching a single result you've got a single branch.

Git has syntax for specifying commits by message. `@^{/^Problem.1:}` will find the most recent commit whose message starts `Problem.1:` (or `Problem 1:`, `.` being a wildcard in the search syntax). So just do it that way.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with rewriting history nobody else has seen yet. You wouldn't publish any other work without a rewrite pass, don't do it with code.

```
A---B---C---D---E    master
```

and you want to smoosh things in `C` and `D` around and split it into three stages for a cleaner presentation.

```
git checkout D
git reset B
possibly a `git add -N .` for files added later
git commit -p
git commit -p 
git commit -p
git replace D @
git filter-branch -- @..master
```

and you've got a rewritten history, with the original in `refs/original/refs/heads/master`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using directory per lesson

[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvval.png)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.